# Help needed on op amp chip and identifiers

Tags: operational-amplifier

[image]

Hi all.

I am starting my own company designing selling studio/guitar based gear.  My first item is a distortion pedal.  I spent years testing pedals etc, and came down to two op amp chips I liked.  The NOS JRC and a burr brown.  I leaned towards the burr brown and that is what I'm going with when it comes to designing my own pedal.

So in the development stage I ordered 10 BB chips among others to do my tests/prototypes and they worked out great.   After a few revisions designing with an overseas manufacturer the prototypes sounded great.

So I've purchased hundreds of my pedals, I've had the boxes silkscreened and all of the electric aspects/components are being soldered.  I've shipped them my own stash of NOS pure copper solid core internal wire, quality solder and 100's of these NOS burr brown chips from the same manufacturer I got the initial 10 from (only a year later).

I've just been told production has ground to a halt because the first 3 production pedals sound different/off compared to my prototype. They narrowed the audio issue down to the chips and asked did I get the wrong chips as they suspect they are fake/copies, and I explained I got them from the same people I got the initial 10 from.

I never saw the large chip order because I shipped that straight to the manufacturer.  So I asked were there any visual differences and they noticed that the codes are different and an r is missing.

Please check out the images.  Should I be having this issue?  What do the lower codes signify on the chips?  They are different to the initial 10 prototype chips that look like the top image.

Below are the bulk order/faulty ones.   A year has passed.  Are these fakes or just a new batch of production with different codes?  Do the codes mean different voltages or something?  I'm not experienced with op amp chips etc.

I'm worried because nobody else produces the original specific lower code on this Opa2143pa chip.  So I'm worried that all my boards will only work with the obsolete chips and not sound as good?

[image]

Comment: TI lists the OPA2134PA as "ACTIVE", so there should be no need to go for NOS.

Comment: The R, if I'm reading this correctly is just the register trademark graphic. (You're talking about the R in the circle?) Are you 100% sure they have swapped one of the new chips for one of the originals in the latest builds and had it sounding as expected?

Comment: The lower codes will be batch and date codes BTW

Comment: It would be helpful to identify what is electrically different about this batch of opamps. Gain? Noise? THD? CMRR? PSRR? etc maybe they are in spec

Comment: Hi Ignacio.  I'd rather have what I tested initially.  It's subtle but in my experience the NOS JRC chips sound a little better than the current batch.  They are much stronger physically as they used better more conductive metal.  Current production JRC chips legs are like tin foil compared to the old ones.  You can only tell the difference by the finish on the top of the chip.  The new ones are dull and the vintage ones have a gloss sheen.  So that experience with the older chips has made me gravitate towards the NOS right or wrong.  Haha.

Comment: Thanks Debosco.  That is a relief on the codes just being date related.  What is the significance of he missing R?  R =  Registered trademark right?  Does that just prove it's NOS?  Or do Current chips still have the R and I'm dealing with fakes?

Comment: Since the lower codes are date codes, is there a webpage with a date decoder (or better still date generator) so I can at least buy from batches earlier or closer to my originals?  They have that type of generator for Gibson serial dating etc online.  I was wondering if there was one for BB chips?

Comment: Date codes on PDIPs are almost always YYWW.

Comment: I only can emphasize what sstobbe said. Maybe the sound of your boxes relies on some OpAmp parameter that did not vary much among your 10 prototype samples but varies much between prototype and production ICs (because they come from different batches) and the variation may still be within the specified variation. So you should find out the **electrical** difference of the OpAmps in order to determine whose fault it is (seller/manufacturer or designer).

Comment: I think you are the 'victim' of TI merging / updating  fabrication plants. This happened with Unitrode; BB was acquired in 2000, and there is usually a 10 year hiatus, but after that the fabrication may have moved to a different fab. The parts will *still meet the datasheet*, but may have subtle differences to the units you previously made. As your new data codes are both from 2013, I strongly suspect this to be the case.

Comment: Thanks Curd/Peter.  That's frustrating as a chunk of my savings are on the line.  But that's good info.  I've just purchased 25 chips that have the R silkscreen.  Different date codes but hopefully the R signifies the old build.   What galls me is the online store/chip image they displayed as I placed my bulk production order is identical to my NOS one.  It's STILL showing the older chip, but shipping the newer ones.

Comment: Having done stints in the audio industry and played in bands for many years as well as designing electronics all my adult life, I find it hard to believe a distortion pedal would be that much in the hands of an op amp changing from batch to batch. If it really is, my belief would be the design needs tweaking because it should not depend on such tolerances.

Comment: DiBosco. Here is one of my dozens of tests.  It's harder to hear as youtube degrades/normalizes the audio and I only used an SM57 so the upper and lower freqs are not very present, but it gives you an idea of the subtle differences between op amp chips/my findings. Tube screamers with the old JRC chips from 81-83 tend to go for 4 times as much as current production tube screamers.  But they have different resistors too.  This is the same pedal with the chip swapped. Go to about 2 mins.    https://youtu.be/r6rSixawg0Y

Comment: First read the datasheet, sometimes the manufacturers do make changes to the parts, read a previous rev and then the current rev. Depending on what kind of circuit this part is in, you may have differences from manufacturing tolerances.

Comment: Laptop2d.  Thanks for that answer!  I just checked datasherts for every rev on the burr brown chip and it's obvious!  On page 63 on the 2001 rev compared with page 11 on the 2015 rev I noticed At TA = 25°C, VS = 15 V, RL = 2 kΩ, unless otherwise noted.  So since it's otherwise noted that made me remember the 2010 rev page 34 the output voltage swing variant correlated to Closed-Loop Output Impedance vs Frequency. So the key for me was the "otherwise noted" info pointed at a drag on the quiescent value.

Comment: Thanks for all your help guys. I missed a few of your answers as I'm new to the message board format/missed the "show more answers" button so i skipped a few queries.  I feel a bit better now that there are differences in revs/functionality in different builds/dates.  I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: CURD at this point I think the issue is with the seller of the chips.  The website of my production/bulk batch at the time of purchase had the exact image (above that is seated in the chip mount) of my OP.  But the chips they sent me look like the 2 loose ones.  Perhaps the installation my manufacturer is in has a little more juice in their facility.  And the new chips voltage tolerances are flakier.

Answer (score 1):

It is well-known that there are fakes of this chip about. If you depended on a contract manufacturer to source the chips they may well have bought remarked chips of some other kind. This kind of shenanigans goes on **all the time**. They may not even have known they were buying crap, only that they got a better price than they expected (and pocketed the difference).

I suggest you start buy purchasing a few known-genuine chips from a distributor such as Digikey (if you're in the US or Canada you'll have them tomorrow most likely) and test those.

It's also possible your circuit design is defective, but given the history I would suspect the sketchy source first.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot trust semiconductor manufacturers to maintain production lines as UNCHANGED. Yield-enhancement experiments are always occurring, and the pass-fail test often is "does the IC pass the final-test on a Teradyne?".

Then, as was written in comments, when TI pushes for more cost-reduction, and a new fab line is used in Dallas (or Beijing), all bets are off.